# no option for database templates in new item window

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022

I'm creating asp.net core web application and there'is no database templates in new item window. I've installed "Data storing and processing", "Entity framework 6 tools". I'm actually want to create ADO.net template, but it seems to be I need to install something for any database templates to appeared
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ADO.net template is removed in Asp.Net core.And NET Framework, as Entity Framework 6 doesn't support . NET Core.So you should use Entity Framework Core rather than Entity framework in Asp.net core.

If you want to use Entity Framework Core with an Existing Database in Asp.net core,you can refer to the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like normal behavior. In .NET Core you'll need to use Entity Framework Core. If you're trying to reference an existing database, you'll need to scaffold it as they've done away with EDMX models in EF Core. Here's how:

1. If you don't have it already, install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` NuGet package and any other EF Core packages you think you might need. For example, if you're developing against SQL Server, install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` package.
2. Run the scaffolding command in the VS Package Manager Console for the database you're trying to add. Something like the following, although you'll want to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) first to determine the parameters you need:

   ```
   Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=(local);Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
   ```

This will create a context class for your database that you can then reference throughout your project.